# mocking an angular http request

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have a view that hits an endpoint to share a resource with another user.  The endpoint would look something like:

```
http://mysite/api/{resource}/{Id}/transfer
```

This is a PUT request and I send a payload that looks like:

```
{ destination: Id, 
data: [Ids of resources that are being transferred]
}
```

I don't understand how I would create a test for the api with mocks?  The endpoint itself just returns a 200.  When I manually check it in the UI, I have to go to the page that has the destinationId and see if that resource is now there.

From what I understand, you can create a

```
when("GET", {url: url}).respond(...);
```

But like I said my service only returns a 200.  I don't really see how I would create a mock service that pretends to transfer something since if it doesn't actually transfer the resource like it does in an actual test environment, then the service isn't working.

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to test the sender (UI) or receiver (API) of the HTTP request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Mock the http like as following.
Here is my Controller:

```
var app = angular.module("angularModule",[]);
```

app.controller("angularController", function ($scope,$http) {

```
$scope.getAddress = function () {
    $http.get("/address").success(function (data) {
        $scope.Address = data;
    });
};

$scope.saveUser = function(user) {
    $http.post("/addUser", user).success(function() {

    });
};
```

});

And i write unit test to check the above controllers Get and POST method as :

```
describe("Test Angular Hello World", function () {
var scope;
var controller;
var httpBackend;
beforeEach(module("angularModule"));

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend) {
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    $httpBackend.expectGET("/userName").respond("Sankalpa");
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller("angularController", { $scope: scope });
    $httpBackend.flush();
}));

it("Should get user address from server", function () {
    httpBackend.expectGET("/address").respond("Horana");
    scope.getAddress();
    httpBackend.flush();

    expect(scope.Address).toEqual("Horana");
});

it("Should save user", function () {
    var user = {id:1, name:'test'};
    httpBackend.expectPOST("/addUser", user).respond(200);
    scope.saveUser(user);
    httpBackend.flush();
});
```

});

Hope this Help :)